# How can I use a link to navigate between input boxes?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, hyperlink

How can I use a link to navigate between input boxes? So if I click the link it will focus on a specific input box. The solution can be with PHP, CSS, JavaScript or HTML.

So:

```
<a href='link1' class='link'>
```

Will navigate to/focus on

```
<input type='text' id='input1' class='input'>
```

And

```
<a href='link2' class='link'>
```

Will navigate to/focus on

```
<input type='text' id='input2' class='input'>
```

P.S: I may also use jQuery

Comment: I think jquery's .focus() might be helpful with this

Comment: @AndyHolmes It's not jQuery's `.focus()`, but JavaScript's. jQuery's `.focus()` binds an event handler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
<a href='link1' class='link' onclick="document.getElementById('input1').focus(); return false;">link1</a>
<input type='text' id='input1' class='input'>
```

Define the onclick event for every link, with the input box id, according to example

http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/xWXg6/

### Alternative - with JQuery:

If you have link and input with the same classes and id like this :

```
<a href='link1' class='link'>link1</a>
<input type='text' id='input1' class='input'>

<a href='link2' class='link'>link2</a>
<input type='text' id='input2' class='input'>
```

then use JQuery:

```
$('.link').each(function(i, e){
    $(this).click(function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        $('#input' + (i+1)).focus();
    });
});
```

Demo2: http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/zNqtB/

Comment: +1, but perhaps a jquery selector is better as it will be cross-browser compliant.

Comment: @Moo-Juice thanks for suggestion, I have updated the code with JQuery as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<label>` for this.

If you want to be done in jQuery.

```
$( ".link" ).click(function() {
    $('#input1').get(0).focus();  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use label for this purpose:

```
<label for="input1"> input1 label </label>
<input type="text" id="input1">
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bXGtM/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$( ".link" ).click(function() {
  $(this).next('input[type="text"]').focus();
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xWXg6/2/)